# Update table with FK column values from related table

Tags: java, hibernate, sql-update, database-relations

Hibernate entities used.
There are `Address` and `Room` entities and apropriate tables in DB.
`Address` can have multiple `Room`s.

Both tables have `address_Id` and `customerEmailAddress`
These columns are `FK` in `Room` table,that references to `Address` table.

There is already `Address` record in DB.
It's needed to add several Rooms to `this` Address.

How to organize Hibernate relation with annotations between `Address` and `Room`, so `Room` table to be updated with appropriate attributes from Address:
`address_Id` and `customerEmailAddress`

Java part looks like:

```
    Room room = new Room();
    Address addr  = someService.getAddressFromSession();
    room.add(addr);
    entityManager.persist(room);
    Room room2 = new Room();
    room2.add(addr);
    entityManager.persist(room2);
```

DB outcome (Room table) should be following:
**id**||**addressId**|| **customerEmailAddress** 
1 || 3                    || mail3@a.com
2 || 3                    || mail3@a.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned about primary keys of both the tables. Assuming both the tables have their own primary keys, 
I think you can have standard mapping done between `Address` and `Room` objects using component model as below:

1. Map `address_id` and `customerEmailAddress` as a **component**. Refer the documentation for component mapping here-- [**Hibernate Component Mapping**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/components.html#components-compositeid).
2. Add `rooms` in `Address` and `One-To-Many` relationship using component defined above and set `cascade` to `All`.
3. Add `address` in `Room` as `Many-To-One` using component defined above.
4. Define one `addRoom` method in `Address` as below(conceptually):

   ```
     public void addRoom(Room room){
          if(this.rooms == null){
              this.rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();
          }
          room.setAddress(this);
          this.rooms.add(room);
     }
   ```
5. Now you can simply work at `Address` level. To save the `room`, add the `room` to `address` and save the address.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi Yogendra,thank you for hint.I will feedback soon how it works.

Comment: got `...MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry...`,while persisting `Address`,as far it's aready exists in DB. Perhaps ,I should use other `CascadeType`?

Comment: Is there are other constraint in your room table? Also please make sure, all the room objects are populated with `Id` (primary key) except the new room object. All old room objects should have been the originally loaded objects ONLY. Hibernate uses primary key to determine, whether it is insert or update. Also **use `merge` in place of `persist`** to avoid duplicate constraint exception.

Comment: it looks like the problem was in that `customerEmailAddress` and `addressId` were defined as `unique key` on mysql create script.that means that they should be unique as far they represent `tuple`.

Comment: Good to know your problem is resolved. If you think the answer was helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.